# Failing to gather info with a cronjob

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-ec2

I am creating an instance with this command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-01bc990364452ab3e --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --user-data file://C:/Users/MARSHAL/Desktop/IXT/h3/sysinfo.sh --key-name it-step-testvm-secretkey --subnet-id subnet-0f98bf197b4bbf6f5 --security-group-ids sg-0c63c870579a6822d
```

This is the content of my sysinfo.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! rpm -q cronie; then
    sudo yum install cronie -y
fi

sudo systemctl enable cronie
sudo systemctl start cronie

cat <<EOF > /root/sysinfo.sh
#!/bin/bash

date_info=\$(date)

system_info=\$(w)

memory_info=\$(free -m)
disk_info=\$(df -h)

open_ports=\$(ss -tulpn)

ping_info=\$(ping -c1 -w1 ukr.net)

suid_info=\$(find / -type f -perm -4000)

echo "date and time: \$date_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "system info: \$system_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "memory usage: \$memory_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "disk space: \$disk_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "open ports: \$open_ports" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "ping info: \$ping_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
echo "SUID programs: \$suid_info" >> /var/log/sysinfo
EOF

chmod +x /root/sysinfo.sh

echo "* * * * 1-5 /root/sysinfo.sh" >> /etc/crontab

service cron restart
```

But when i connect to my instance and trying to check I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-82-226 ~]$ cat /var/log/sysinfo
cat: /var/log/sysinfo: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what the problem is(maybe something with paths)

Comment: What `ls -la /var/log` is showing?

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-188 ~]$ ls -la /var/log
total 1416
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root   root             16384 Nov  9 11:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root   root               266 Nov  9 11:16 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root   root                39 Oct 26 18:15 README -> ../../usr/share/doc/systemd/README.logs
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root                17 Nov  9 11:16 amazon
drwx------.  2 root   root                23 Nov  9 11:16 audit
etc

Comment: You should check the `/var/log/syslog` file for any errors reported by cron.

Comment: try with a simple `echo "hello" >> /tmp/sysinfo` inside your cron and share us the result. Also at the first line of script (after #!/bin/bash)  `echo "start" >> /tmp/sysinfo` inside your cron